# monotonically increasing sequence when the integral converges

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and $J_a(f)$ be $$J_a(f)=\frac{1}{a}\int^{a}_0 f(x)dx $$
for $a>0$. I know $\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty}J_a(f)=A$ when $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=A$ and the inverse may not hold. Then I want to show there is a monotonically increasing sequence $0\leq x_1\leq x_2\leq \cdots$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n=\infty$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(x_n)=A$ when $\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty}J_a(f)=A$.

Please give me some advice.

Comment: Try working with the differences $J_a - \frac{1}{2}J_{a/2}$.  First of all, what can you say about these differences?  And what can this tell you about the values of $f$?

Comment: What is a "uniformly increasing sequence"? Just a monotonically increasing sequence, or is there some condition on e.g. $(x_{n+1} - x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: @felipeh: OK. I think. Just a minutes.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Sorry. "monotonically" is correct. Lack of my vocabulary.

Comment: @felipeh: These differences seem converge to $\frac{A}{2}$, that is, $\frac{1}{a}\int_{\frac{a}{2}}^a f(x)dx$ converge to $\frac{A}{2}$...

Comment: Now multiply with $2$ so that you have the average of $f$ on $[a/2,a]$ and use the mean value theorem of integration. As an alternative way, note that the assumption that such a sequence doesn't exist implies either $\limsup\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x) < A$ or $\liminf\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x) > A$. But $$\limsup_{a\to\infty} J(a) \leqslant \limsup_{x\to\infty} f(x)\qquad\text{and}\qquad \liminf_{a\to\infty} J(a) \geqslant \liminf_{x\to\infty} f(x).$$

Comment: @DanielFischer: It is a contradict, so there is such a sequence. I got it. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that $2J(2^n)-J(2^{n-1})\to A$, as $n\to \infty$.
but there exsist a $x_n\in[2^{n-1},2^n]$, such that
$$
2J(2^n)-J(2^{n-1})=\frac1{2^{n-1}}\int_{2^{n-1}}^{2^n} f(x)dx=f(x_n)
$$